# Run certain plugins only when "advanced" conditions are met

Tags: maven

In my maven build there are some plugins that I only would like to run when certain conditions are met. I am aware of how profiles work but I am afraid that the activation element is too simple for these cases.

The most common condition would be to run the plugin only if a certain file or set of files has been changed since the last build.

The reason is that some plugins are time consuming and if the files I am refering to have not been changed since the last run, there is no point in running the plugin.

Comment: In my opinion, it should be plugin's responsibility to check that files have changed since the last run.

Comment: I agree, but if that is not the case, is there any other solution?

Comment: If the plugin supports a `<skip>` configuration parameter, you could write a simple plugin that sets a specified property if one set of files is newer than another, bind that plugin early in the lifecycle and have the property be referenced in the `<skip>` config parameter. That is really the only way to work around plugins that are not doing what they should be (namely checking if they need to do the work they do)

Comment: Thanks Stepen. If you leave your comment as an answer I will mark it as the accepted answer.